# How to operate Active Directory with DNS on another computer?

Tags: networking, active-directory, dns

Is it possible to operate Active Directory while the DNS server is running on another computer ? or it should be installed exactly on the Active Directory running computer ? thnx.

Comment: SO is a programming stack exchange, You would have a better audience on 'server fault' or 'super admin' stack exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install Active Directory without having DNS on your network, because Active Directory uses DNS as its location service.

However, you can install DNS separately, without Active Directory. If you install DNS on a domain controller, you can also choose whether or not to use Active Directory to provide storage and replication for DNS. Using Active Directory for storage and replication provides some benefits like :
Increased fault tolerance, Security, Easier management, More efficient replication of large zones.

Have a look to [Setting Up DNS for Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959341.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible.A DNS zone is the contiguous portion of the DNS domain name space over which a DNS server has authority or is authoritative.In all DNS is the authority level registration.